# possible ways to print out a char* that's set to NULL?

Tags: c++

I have a default constructor that sets all member variables to an empty state, later when I run the program it creates 3 objects (1 empty, 2 with content) when it comes time to print the empty object it crashes because of it not being able to print NULL.

I tried setting the char* variable to "" (see below) and it worked on visual studios but on the school's compiler it returned the error "warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘char’ from NULL" so I was wondering is there another way to get around this?

Alternatively is there another way to have the char* be set to a safe recognizable empty state?

```
/*doing the strcpy*/
Item::Item(){
    _price = 0;
    _quantity = 0;
    _name = NULL;
   _name = new char[1];
    strcpy(_name, "");
    _sku[0] = NULL;
}
```

The declaration of the member variables:

```
class Item : public PosIO {
private:
    char _sku[MAX_SKU_LEN + 1];
    char* _name;
    double _price;
    bool _taxed;
    int _quantity;
```

Comment: declaration for _name: char* _name

Comment: @GManNickG I cant change the type of _name

Comment: What's `_sku`? Are you sure the warning is for `_name`?

Comment: @deviantfan _sku is char _sku[MAX_SKU + 1] and yes I'm sure because sku print's as an empty string ("") when it tries printing _name is when it crashes

Comment: I am guessing that `_sku` is defined to be of type `char*` . Hence, the compiler is complaining about `_sku[0] = NULL;`.  But that's only a guess. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StanleyDharan Instead of judging by crashes, just look at the line number of your warning. `_sku[0] = NULL;` => `_sku[0] = '\0';` and it works (without warning, the crash is something else). NULL is only for pointers.

Comment: I did do a test where I printed a char* variable being set to null and it crashed. @RSahu

Comment: @StanleyDharan You're confusing yourself. There are *two* completely independent problems. One causes a crash, one just a warning (harmless warning in this case). What should be treated first?

Comment: @deviantfan Im aware its a warning but its still preventing submission (school compiler is extremely picky)

Comment: Well, for the warning part, I already told you what to do. For the crash part, someone else posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize `_name` to '\0' which is the end character (a character that indicates that a string ,or array of characters, end). This way your variable exists and has data, but nothing can be printed.

Also please note that a pointer is "safe" when it is `NULL`, the fact that your program crashes when it tried to print it is normal, in fact you should check if the pointer is `NULL` or not before printing it (assuming you expect it to be NULL at some point).

```
char *pt = NULL;

/* ... code ... */

if (pt != NULL)
    printf("%c", pt);
```

Comment: Okay I see what your saying, so I guess in my operator<< overload I should use an if statement saying if(_name == NULL) print something else?

Comment: @StanleyDharan So you did a `_name = '\0';` ? That's so wrong... _name is a *pointer*. Please don't start guessing around, that way you won't ever finish.

Comment: @deviantfan yah no I understand what he's saying now

Comment: @deviantfan actually I wasn't referring to `_name = '\0';` but rather making the pointer to look at a `\0`, so he can print it without crashing.

Comment: @TomTsagk I wasn't referring to your answer, but OPs comment.

Answer (score 0):

Printing a null pointer is undefined behavior but if you *really* want to allow the possibility of setting your variable to a null pointer, you could use a shorthand if statement to print "NULL" if the variable is a null pointer and whatever the variable points to if it isn't a null pointer

```
char *a = nullptr;
printf("%s", (a == nullptr) ? "NULL" : a);
```